# Don't understand why while runs itself again after ignoring a command

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I have this code in JS

```js
//param A : array of integers
//param B : array of integers
//return an integer
function doesitwork(A, B) {
  if (A.length != B.length) {
    return -1;
  }
  var i = 0;
  var tank;
  var count;
  var johnny = true;
  for (var j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
    count = 0;
    tank = 0;
    i = j;
    johnny = true;
    while (count < A.length && johnny == true) {
      console.log(i);
      console.log(A.length);
      console.log(count);
      console.log(johnny);
      tank += A[i];
      if (B[i] <= tank)
        tank -= B[i];
      else {
        johnny = false;
      }
      count++;
      i++;
      if (i == A.length)
        i == 0;

    }
    while (johnny == true) {
      if (count == A.length)
        return j;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

var A = [1, 2];
var B = [2, 1];
console.log(doesitwork(A, B));
```

What I don't understand is when I run the program, at first count = 0, but when I enter the while loop for the first time, instead of running the command count++ and changing its value to 1, it doesn't run it, keeps count at 0 and then changes it after re-entering the loop.

TLDR: While loop is running twice with one of the variables staying with the same value instead of changing it as one of the lines in the loop suggests.

Comment: How are you determining the behavior you're reporting? Can you provide example input, and the output that shows this is doing what you say it's doing? Also, are you aware that `i == 0;`  doesn't do anything?

Comment: If   `johnny` is  `true`, and `count` does not equal `A.length`, you have an infinite loop.

Comment: The format of your code makes it really hard to read. I used the snipplet and its format function to make it readable and runnable

Comment: It goes into for, it goes into while, it goes back to the for, it goes into while, it loops again in while, it exits.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I know it was a mistake on my part which I noticed afterwards but it isn't connected to the problem.

Comment: @epascarello I know, that's why I'm using count++, to get count's value higher and once it reaches a certain value the loop will stop. Problem is when I run it and use the console to check what's wrong I can see that count++ does't change its value in the first time the loop runs. That's what im trying to figure out

Comment: Make  `count = 0;` outside the for loop

Comment: Every time you go back to the for loop it resets..... Set a break point and walk through the code with the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TLDR: While loop is running twice with one of the variables staying with the same value instead of changing it as one of the lines in the loop suggests.

You're assuming that `count` never got incremented, because you're assuming the `while` loop continues a second time around. In reality, the `while` loop exits after a single iteration, and the `for` loop resets `count` to `0`. Then the `while` loop is entered again, but with a different value for `j`.

#### Details

The first time through your `while` loop, `B[i]` is `2` and `A[i]` is `1`. `tank += A[i]` makes `tank` have a value of `1`. Therefore, `b[i] <= tank` is `false`, so you set `johnny` to `false`. That means at the end of that iteration, your `while` condition (`... && johnny == true`) is `false`, so you don't continue through the `while` loop a second time.

Instead, control moves out to the `for` loop, which resets `count` to `0`.

To debug issues like this in the future, it helps to learn to use the debugger: you can place a breakpoint where you want, and see how the control flows and how the variables change as you step through it. If you find that's not possible, you may need to be even more verbose with your logging, as below.

```js
//param A : array of integers
//param B : array of integers
//return an integer
function doesitwork(A, B) {
  if (A.length != B.length) {
    return -1;
  }
  var i = 0;
  var tank;
  var count;
  var johnny = true;
  for (var j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
    console.log("entering for loop");
    count = 0;
    tank = 0;
    i = j;
    johnny = true;
    while (count < A.length && johnny == true) {
      console.log("entering while loop");
      console.log("i", i);
      console.log("j", j);
      console.log("A.length", A.length);
      console.log("count", count);
      console.log("johnny", johnny);
      tank += A[i];
      if (B[i] <= tank)
        tank -= B[i];
      else {
        console.log(B[i], tank, "setting johnny to false");
        johnny = false;
      }
      count++;
      i++;
      if (i == A.length)
        i == 0;

    }
    while (johnny == true) {
      if (count == A.length)
        return j;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

var A = [1, 2];
var B = [2, 1];
console.log(doesitwork(A, B));
```

Comment: I was a little confused at start but it's clear now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what are you trying to do but the condition of the `while` loop will not be always true which makes `count= 0` inside the `for` loop. So, you need to put `var count =0;`

```js
//param A : array of integers
//param B : array of integers
//return an integer
function doesitwork(A, B) {
  if (A.length != B.length) {
    return -1;
  }
  var i = 0;
  
  var tank;
  var count=0;
  var johnny = true;
  for (var j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
   
    tank = 0;
    i = j;
    johnny = true;
    while (count < A.length && johnny == true) {
      console.log(i);
      console.log(A.length);
      console.log(count);
      console.log(johnny);
      tank += A[i];
      if (B[i] <= tank)
        tank -= B[i];
      else {
        johnny = false;
      }
      count++;
      i++;
      if (i == A.length)
        i == 0;

    }
    while (johnny == true) {
      if (count == A.length)
        return j;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

var A = [1, 2];
var B = [2, 1];
console.log(doesitwork(A, B));
```